# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when server is hit by mutiple users at the same time

Tags: java, http, web

I am stuck with this problem where my application can be hit by around 1000 users at the same time. While it is giving following exception after 600 users.

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
```

In server.xml, maxThreads = 200 (default) value is set. I do not want to increase this to run more users as it will cause lots of memory usage.

All of http requests are taking 10 - 60ms if one user access the server at one time. Can some body please guide me how should I proceed with the analysis to see if the application can be improved in some way.

Comment: Is keepalive enabled?

Comment: Please describe your envirnoment.

Comment: Please describe your *application.* Is it multithreaded? Are you setting an absurdly low value for the backlog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a solution other than raising maxThreads. It's exactly what it is there for. Bear in mind that it will not create 1000 threads right away, it's just the maximum value it will use in case of receiving many incoming connections.

If you want threads to be destroyed 'after the storm', use the maxSpareThreads parameter to make sure not all 1000 threads are kept in the pool

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the quick reply. I can not find maxSpareThreads parameter in the tomcat doc. If i use this, will it kill all the threads once the request is completed? In that case, i will be fine increasing maxThreads value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your reference to `maxThreads` and `server.xml` you are using Tomcat.

Take a look at the Tomcat documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

The server allows creation of additional threads for new requests until `maxThreads` is reached. Beyond this, it adds requests to a queue. The maximum size of the queue is defined by the `acceptCount` on the Connector. What is the value of acceptCount in your server at this time?

You can't arbitrarily keep increasing `acceptCount` either, though you probably do have some flexibility at this point.

The smarter thing to do, in the long run, is to tune your memory usage so that you can have a few more threads running on the same server. Ff you're also using a webserver (like Apache httpd), you should check its configuration too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rajesh. acceptCount is set as default (100).

Comment: Well then try increasing it a little.